# How can I stop Monero wallet safely?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monerod-commands

How can I stop Monero wallet safely? I can't stop the wallet using `exit` command.

When I check network connections by using:

```
netstat -pnt
```

It always shows some monero connection details. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Why can't you stop the wallet using the "exit" command ?

Answer (score 2):

Once you are in the wallet you can simple run `exit`, however it sounds like you want to stop `monerod` (the background daemon). In this case you would run `monerod exit`.

see [How do I gracefully stop the monerod daemon process?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/how-do-i-gracefully-stop-the-monerod-daemon-process) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply farinspace.Now its working....I just tried the command " ./monerod exit " after entering the wallet folder.

Comment: Hi farinspace, i have one more doubt, I need to bind the wallet to a particular port using monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 , then do i need to specify the port number when i going to stop the wallet.? if yes how can specify the port number?

Answer (score 0):

How do you start the wallet? Let's say the command is `monero`, then you can kill the process with `pkill monero`

Comment: Thank you for your reply Endogen.Now its working....I just tried the command " ./monerod exit " after entering the wallet folder.

Comment: Hi Endogen, i have one more doubt, I need to bind the wallet to a particular port using monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18082 , then do i need to specify the port number when i going to stop the wallet.? if yes how can specify the port number?

Comment: You do not need to specify the port number if you want to stop it, as far as i know. It's always the the same command and you want to stop that command. What port the command uses should not matter